# plotting with pcolormesh, changing axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, prettyplotlib

Supppose I am plotting a assymetric matrix with pcolormesh:

```
import prettyplotlib as ppl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ppl.pcolormesh(fig, ax, np.random.randn(10,80))
plt.show()
```

Now I want to change the x-axis such that its extents are for example -500  to 500 without changing the plot, only the labels of the x-axis, the same for y-axis. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: it is better to pass in the correct X/Y arrays to `pcolormesh` so that the tick labels take care of them selves.

Comment: this is a good advice, but could you please show how to do that properly?

Answer (score 0):

After the ppl.pcolormesh command you can define the ticklables directly using

```
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
```

where xticklabels is an array of your desired labels and xticks are the values at which the labels should apply.